# IIS Configuration with HTTPS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, http, iis-7.5, https

I have 2 servers I am setting up. They are both Windows Server 2008 R2. They are both getting IIS setup as web servers. I have set up other servers that we currently have in production. I did the setup the same way, and did the security certificates and keyed them right.

The old servers I setup, as soon as I add the intermediary certificates, and the security certificate, the address https://myurl.com works just fine. This is assuming I have done port forwarding and opened up the firewall on the server.

So my question is did I miss something that causes these other servers to work for http but anything across https gives the browser the message 501 Not Implemented the request method is not implemented by this server.

I have done side by side comparisons of servers, roles, features, and config files to determine what is different. Everything matches, and the website stuff is a copy of the working stuff, the only difference is the url is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found my solution. It turns out, in my port forwarding, there is an enabled check-box on enabling the rule you just added, having missed that on this one 80 was some how enabled while 443 wasn't. It turns out every thing was set up, but one little check-box was missed in the router settings.

Comment: IOW, the issue was not an IIS issue, but rather was a firewall config issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the site bindings for each site that you want to enable SSL on and bind https to whatever IP your site runs on.

[image]

Comment: Yes this I know, and it is done. At this point my other servers were able to serve the URL in https, but for some reason the same process gets me error 501 Not Implemented now